# Can I view my down voted posts separately

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

Is there any way (or hacks) to view my down voted posts alone in SO? Is there an option (in the user page, I presume)  to view my posts that were recently down voted? If not, wouldn't it be nice to have such a `Down Voted` tab that lists my recently down voted posts so that I can spot them easily to understand what was wrong?

Comment: You make feature-requests here on Meta and explain why you want it or why it would be good or some other paalava.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the envelope next to your user name, then go to the reputation tab and choose the time frame you're interested in. Anything that's red is something that lost you reputation. This includes -2 for a downvote you made yourself on someone else's answers/questions, but that shouldn't be two hard to distinguish from downvotes on *your* answers.

Note, though, that this will *not* show you downvotes on CW questions / answers, because these don't do anything to your rep.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this. I was wondering if there's a way to view only the down voted posts.

Comment: BTW, where can I make a request for this (or any other) feature? Here itself or is there another place for that?

Comment: No, this is just the right place. After a while, most questions tagged "feature-request" will gain one of the red tags like "status-deferred" or "status-declined" (or even "status-completed").